# Qual a diferença entre random.choice e random.choices em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Sei que ambos 'sorteiam' números aleatórios , mas qual a diferença entre eles ?

Comment: Se a resposta abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar. 

Answer (score 6):

Existem duas diferenças fundamentais:

1. `random.choice` retorna **um elemento** da sequência sorteada, enquanto `random.choices` retorna uma **lista** de elementos da sequência sorteada
2. `random.choices` aceita pesos para as observações, enquanto o peso das observações é igual para todos os elementos em `random.choice`

Veja como a diferença nos argumentos da função permitem inferir essas diferenças:

Argumentos `random.choice`

```py
import random
import inspect

#argumentos random.choice
inspect.getfullargspec(random.choice)
```

```
FullArgSpec(args=['self', 'seq'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```

Argumentos `random.choices`

```py
#argumentos random.choices
inspect.getfullargspec(random.choices)
```

```
FullArgSpec(args=['self', 'population', 'weights'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=(None,), kwonlyargs=['cum_weights', 'k'], kwonlydefaults={'cum_weights': None, 'k': 1}, annotations={})
```

Um exemplo de seleção aleatória de uma sequência usando `random.choices`:

```py
import random

#seleciona dois números a partir de um vetor de observações e um vetor de pesos
print(random.choices([1,4,2,7,4,2,8,9], [0.2,0.4,0.6,0.3, 0.5,0.4,0.7,0.3], k=2)) #[4,8] no meu caso
```

Note que não é possível replicar esse exemplo usando `random.choices`, pois não há opção para aplicar pesos. Mas se o usuário desejasse criar uma lista, também seria possível, usando *list comprehension*:

```
[random.choice([1,4,2,7,4,2,8,9]) for k in range(2)]
```